# Issue converting XML to String with TransformerFactory with access external DTD disabled

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert the following XML to String with TransformerFactory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TransactionRequest>
    <SequenceNo>002285</SequenceNo>
    <TransType>01</TransType>
    <TransAmount>10000</TransAmount>
    <TransCurrency>840</TransCurrency>
    <TransDateTime>2015-10-07T15:49:36-05:00</TransDateTime>
</TransactionRequest>
```

It works fine. But when I try to add the `transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");` line to avoid XML External Entity Injection I am getting error:

```
Error: URI=null Line=2: Document root element "TransactionRequest", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Error: URI=null Line=2: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

My code looks like:

```
public static String documentToString(Document document) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, Constants.LOWERCASE_YES);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, Constants.LOWERCASE_XML);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, Constants.LOWERCASE_YES);
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, Constants.UTF8);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(sw));

        return sw.toString();
    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        logger.error("Error while transforming Xml document to String", ex);
    }
    return Constants.EMPTYSTRING;
}
```

Comment: Which jdk are you using? I'm testing your code with 1.8 and had no problem.

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I tried with openjdk 11.0.2 and couldn't reproduce it.